# addchild setting width and height

Tags: actionscript-3, height, width, addchild

trying to do something pretty straight forward - have a function that adds child from library and sets position and width and height. Is adding fine but for some reason width and height aren't setting properly. Any suggestions?

code:

```
var video1tn:video1_btn = new video1_btn;

function thumbNails1():void{
  addChild(video1tn);
  video1tn.width = 350;
  video1tn.height = 170;
  video1tn.x = 794.95;
  video1tn.y = 85.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try placing a shape with 0 alpha to the background of your `video1_btn`, filling the entire initial size of the `video1_btn`. I have ran into this before and i think this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "aren't setting properly"?  What's the symptom?

Here's a set of width/height debugging tips:

- Try tracing width/height before and after setting it:

  - If they trace 0 before, then assigning >0 values will set their scaleX/Y properties to infinity.
  - Otherwise, if afterward they don't trace what you set, then potentially the video1_btn class is doing something unconventional with the width/height setters.
- Does the component work fine without setting width/height?

  - Try setting scaleX/scaleY instead of width/height
- Maybe the parent container is scaled/transformed oddly?

  - Try adding the component to a container and scaling that instead.
  - Try adding your component to the stage instead.  Try setting with/height or scalex/scaley then and check the behavior.

Comment: The symptom is that they show the wrong size - they show a sliver of the actual symbol in the library instead of the entire library item.

Comment: It's returning the proper dimensions when I do what you said above

Comment: Added some more debug tips